# Push clear all channels

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, channel

I'm using the parse.com Push library and it's just awesome! Especially for indie projects it's great to have a free alternative (We used to use UrbanAirShip before until they removed our account without saying anything...)
Subscribing to a channel works just fine and also unsubscribing works fine.
The thing is that we only want 1 channel to be there (+ the broadcast channel).
So if I subscribe to the channel "1" and then want to change to channel "2" I want to remove channel "1" and use the new channel "2".

How would I achieve that? I didn't find any ParsePush.unsubscribeAll() or anything like it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming Android)

You're probably after [`ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground`](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParsePush.html#unsubscribeInBackground%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the android tag.... Can't unsubscribeInBackground only subscribe 1 channel?

Comment: It looks like it can only unsubscribe from one channel. If you want to completely wipe the list of channels the installation is subscribed to and replace it with something else, then maybe you can use `setChannels`: https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParsePush.html#setChannels%28java.util.Collection%29